# How to extract colour using NLP from a review?

Tags: python, nlp

```
import spacy

class ColourExtractorStrict:
    def __init__(self, colours):
        self.colours = colours
        self.pos_ok = ['ADJ', 'NOUN']
        self.tagger = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

    def get(self, string):
        extracted = set()
        doc = self.tagger(string.lower())
        pairs = [(word.text, word.pos_) for word in doc]
        for index, pair in enumerate(pairs):
            text, pos = pair
            if text in self.colours:
                text_ahead = self.look_ahead(pairs=pairs, index=index)
                text_behind = self.look_behind(pairs=pairs, index=index,
                                               colour_pos=pos)
                if text_behind:
                    text_behind.append(text)
                    if text_ahead:
                        text_behind.extend(text_ahead)
                        extracted.add(' '.join(text_behind))
                    else:
                        extracted.add(' '.join(text_behind))
                elif text_ahead:
                    extracted.add(' '.join([text] + text_ahead))
                else:
                    extracted.add(text)

        return extracted if extracted else False

    def look_ahead(self, pairs, index):
        ahead = list()
        for text, pos in pairs[index + 1:]:
            if pos in self.pos_ok:
                ahead.append(text)
            else:
                break

        return ahead if ahead else False

    def look_behind(self, pairs, index, colour_pos):
        behind = list()
        for text, pos in reversed(pairs[:index]):
            if pos in self.pos_ok:
                behind.append(text)
            else:
                break

        return list(reversed(behind)) if behind else False


colours = ['blue', 'pink', 'lavender', 'heather']
for row in fashion_data['review_text'].iteritems():
    ColourExtractorStrict(colours=colours).get(string = row)
```

I would like to iterate over the rows of the column review_text to extract the colours only. But I faced the error of `'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'` in the  `get()` method after line:

```
    doc = self.tagger(string.lower())
```

Please enlighten me if you will!

Comment: The error mean `self.tagger()` returned a tuple and you're trying to index it with the string returned by calling `string.lower()`. Disclaimer: I know nothing about NLP.

Comment: I suggest you read through the documentation about rule-based matching in spaCy. https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching